# How to copy data from one table to another?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an application with some searching, where I have a number of search terms.

I would like to do something like.

```
for( each_search_term ) {
     INSERT INTO tmpTable SELECT dataId FROM SearchTable WHERE _id = ?;
}
```

I wasn't sure if the supported way is like the code below, or if there is some other better supported method.

```
void doInsert( SqliteDatabase db, long dataId ) {
     db.execSQL( "INSERT INTO tmpTable SELECT dataId FROM SearchTable WHERE _id = ?;", new String [] { String.valueOf( dataId ) } );
}
```

The developer documents seem to imply that execSQL is not for INSERT operations.

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

Comment: The docs are bad. You can safely ignore "Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE"

Comment: `The developer documents seem to imply that execSQL is not for INSERT operations.` I do successfully use `execSQL()` for INSERT operations. Well, I use it for ALL commands excluding queries (SELECT). For which, I use `rawQuery()`. I'd rephrase the sentence as `"Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT"` (being a void, it doesn't return anything).

Comment: The differentiating factor is that `execSQL` does not return a value. Whilst the alternative/recommended(sic) `insert`, `delete` and `update` methods do return values. e.g. `insert` returns the rowid or -1 if no row was inserted, update and delete return the number of rows affected. (*note this is a summary and is not full comprehensive*)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1;........................
```

Use this with

```
db.exeSQL(command);
```